# Is an invulnerable code possible (including brute force attack)?

Tags: encryption, aes, brute-force-attack, multiple-encryption, decryption

If I double encrypted a text with for example AES wouldn't it be invulnerable to bruteforce attacks due to the computer not knowing when it has reached the plain text?

Plain text->1st layer of encryption->2nd layer->output

Comment: Doing two layers of (unauthenticated) encryption is just a less efficient way of encrypting with a key that's twice as large. (Also in general, authenticated encryption is better, so doing a strategy that encourages unauthenticated encryption isn't great.)

Comment: Doing AES directly without a proper mode of operation is bad practice (also see weaknesses of ECB mode). Making things more complicated does not make you more secure, unless you can back it up. And only considering brute-force attacks is quite useless. Today's security requires much more than that.

Comment: It is to my knowledge that prime number codes can only be breaked with a brute force attack. Of course we lack the computational power to do so.However if there are other methods please enlighten me.

Comment: If you want to see actually how hard even known-plaintext attack see the [RSA DES challange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/64863/18298)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will address the question in the title - double encryption with AES has been addressed in the other answers.

As Squeamish Ossifrage pointed out, you do not want in general to rely on the assumption that the adversary cannot verify if a candidate decryption is correct. However, there are situations where you *have to*. Typically, this is the case when the message you want to protect is encrypted with a low-entropy key (e.g., a password). In this case, brute-force attacks become computationally feasible, and it is an interesting and well-studied question to understand when we can mitigate that and achieve *beyond brute-force* security.

The solution to this problem is known as [honey encryption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/155.pdf) (see also [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/174.pdf)). Honey encryption enjoyed quite a number of interesting application, see [Google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?um=1&ie=UTF-8&lr&cites=2311603481412310134) for a list of papers that used it. citing the abstract of the seminal paper that introduced it:

> We introduce honey encryption (HE), a simple, general approach to encrypting messages using low min-entropy
>   keys such as passwords. HE is designed to produce a ciphertext which, when decrypted with any of a number of
>   incorrect keys, yields plausible-looking but bogus plaintexts called honey messages. A key benefit of HE is that it
>   provides security in cases where too little entropy is available to withstand brute-force attacks that try every key;
>   in this sense, HE provides security beyond conventional brute-force bounds. HE can also provide a hedge against
>   partial disclosure of high min-entropy keys.
>
> HE significantly improves security in a number of practical settings. To showcase this improvement, we build
>   concrete HE schemes for password-based encryption of RSA secret keys and credit card numbers. The key challenges are development of appropriate instances of a new type of randomized message encoding scheme called a
>   distribution-transforming encoder (DTE), and analyses of the expected maximum loading of bins in various kinds
>   of balls-and-bins games.

Intuitively, honey encryption will protect even against brute-force attack when your message comes from a known distribution. The idea is to design the encryption scheme such that given a ciphertext $C = E_K(m)$ encrypting a message $m$ sampled from a distribution $D$, then *any* alternative key $K'$ will have the property that $D_{K'}(C)$ looks like a random sample from $D$ - and therefore, brute-force decryption cannot tell appart the right key from the wrong keys.

Honey encryption can be achieved relatively easily for simple distribution. For example, you could want to encrypt your phone number, such that any decryption of the ciphertext with an incorrect key looks like a valid phone number. Or you could want to encrypt a prime (this is an application described in the first paper I referenced).

Answer (score 6):

**No**, If we assume that the mythical computer **can** brute force the multiple AES encryptions and there are many ciphertexts available which are encrypted under the same key and their corresponding plaintext are not random.

The brute-force code can keep track of the meaningful plaintexts for each ciphertext and finally can perform an intersection of possible key candidates to find the key.

**Yes,** If the plaintexts don't contain any meaningful information to distinguish them from random then there will be no possibility. So at least a distinguisher is required.

Comment: An output is supposedly "random" to a certain degree. I doubt there would be enough to identify. Is it theoretically possible to create a distinguisher for that?

Comment: Well, that will really depend on the certain degree. Like in Linear and Differential attacks the degree (there the probability) may require just more ciphertexts to pin the key(s).

Comment: @daviddavid The words 'supposedly random' and 'I doubt' are not a valid arguments on their own, when it comes to security. In contrary to popular belief, security isn't determined by the inability of the author to find a weakness. At the very least, an author of an idea had provide logical arguments with correct probability theory, to even be taken seriously. But then this question might be closed.

Answer (score 3):

When you cascade two ciphers with independent keys, $E_{k_1,k_2}\colon x \mapsto \operatorname{AES}_{k_2}(\operatorname{AES}_{k_1}(x))$, the intelligent adversary will use a [parallel collision search for a meet-in-the-middle attack](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~paulv/papers/JoC97.pdf) at far less than $2^{128}$ or $2^{256}$ times the cost of a search for $k_1$ or $k_2$ alone.

So this technique doesn't improve security nearly as much as you may think it does.  It is often not helpful to simply [add layers of complexity](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/72692): the result [may turn out worse than you thought](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/72778) if you don't [design it to make proving theorems easy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/72758), which is a mistake made [over and over again in real-world protocols](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/71026).  The additional complexity may distract you from other concerns like preventing forgery or malleability, which [can lead to leaking plaintexts](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59241).

---

What about the more general question of knowing whether you're looking at plaintext or not?

From the attacker's perspective, yes, you need some pattern to tell whether you've succeeded in breaking the system or not.

But from the defender's perspective, **we don't usually consider a cipher secure unless it can conceal any pattern *even if the adversary can choose the pattern*.**  Then you don't have to worry about whether the particular patterns of data in *your application* will thwart an adversary or not.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption that an adversary would be unable to verify a successful decryption is not safe. They may for example isolate a piece of encrypted data that they are certain is part of some constant plaintext data (eg. file header) or cross check legible English etc.

I am unsure what your example of double encryption even has to do with it. Usually it's something you do as a hedge against a potential catastrophic flaw in a cipher (you don't use the same cipher multiple times in this case). Or if you are suffering from a too short key (eg. triple DES).